# Trying to understand "Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list" error

Tags: mysql, sql

As I'm trying to understand SQL by playing around with the code a bit, I have run into this situation. I run this code

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE MATCH ( title, location, description ) AGAINST ( 'New York designer')
```

and I get the right row results. However, if I ask myself, "okay so what if I want just look at one column?"

```
 SELECT * FROM  jobs WHERE  match(location) against ('designer')
```

I get the error "Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list". Why? I'm not sure what this error means. I just remove two words and commas.

I alter the jobs table to use the `MyISAM` engine. Does that mean it's searchable or "`FULLTEXT`"? Since `InnoDB` isn't searchable, is that correct to say?

But now, when isolated to searching to one column, it's a problem?

Let me know if this makes sense, I will re-edit.

Comment: `I just remove two words and commas.` Welcome to the profession of software development. In formal languages, a single character is the difference between invalid and valid syntax, or valid syntax with two different meanings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FULLTEXT` indexes are a feature of the `MyISAM` storage engine.

You can't match against the location column unless there is a `FULLTEXT` index on that column alone.

> The MATCH() column list must match exactly the column list in some FULLTEXT index definition for the table, unless this MATCH() is IN BOOLEAN MODE. Boolean-mode searches can be done on nonindexed columns, although they are likely to be slow.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-restrictions.html

Answer (score 1):

when everything was right and  still got this error i found that the KEYS were disabled ..

make sure u have enabled the keys on that table

it didn't work for me when i had disabled the keys ...

i enabled the keys " ALTER TABLE `table name` ENABLE KEYS;

and it worked fine

Comment: In order to verify if the keys are disabled run an EXPLAIN on a SELECT statement that would normally use a key. If the keys are disabled, then the columns possible_keys, key, key_len, ref will return null.