# Can't find FULLTEXT index while using IN BOOLEAN MODE

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, mariadb, match-against

I'm trying to filter some data with an `MATCH ... AGAINST` `WHERE` clause. But I get the following error:

> Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

This is an query I execute:

```
SELECT PAR.idPartij,
       PAR.Partijnaam,
       PRO.Productnaam,
       PER.Perceel,
       R.Ras,
       PAR.TagNR
FROM Partij AS PAR
LEFT OUTER JOIN Product AS PRO ON PAR.idProduct = PRO.idProduct
LEFT OUTER JOIN Ras AS R ON PAR.idRas = R.idRas
LEFT OUTER JOIN Klasse AS K ON PAR.idKlasse = K.idKlasse
LEFT OUTER JOIN Perceel AS PER ON PAR.idPerceel = PER.idPerceel
LEFT OUTER JOIN Maat AS M ON PAR.idMaat = M.idMaat
LEFT OUTER JOIN Teler AS T ON PAR.idTeler = T.idTeler
LEFT OUTER JOIN Handelshuis AS H ON PAR.idHandelshuis = H.idHandelshuis
LEFT OUTER JOIN Behandeling AS BH ON PAR.idBehandeling = BH.idBehandeling
WHERE PAR.Actief <> 0
  AND (
          MATCH(PAR.idPartij) AGAINST ('%1423%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
       OR MATCH(PAR.Partijnaam) AGAINST ('%1423%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
       OR MATCH(PRO.Productnaam) AGAINST ('%1423%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
       OR MATCH(PER.Perceel) AGAINST ('%1423%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
       OR MATCH(R.Ras) AGAINST ('%1423%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
       OR MATCH(PAR.TagNR) AGAINST ('%1423%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  )
ORDER BY PAR.idPartij
```

As you can see, am I using the `IN BOOLEAN MODE` inside the `AGAINST` to overcome this problem as stated by [Dan Grossman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6715727/1175881) but it isn't working.

Am I missing something or am I doing it totally wrong?

*an little side note, the select (and thus the MATCH part) is created dynamically in PHP*

Comment: Did you created fulltext index for the specified fields on those tables ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty No I did not. I thought that the `IN BOOLEAN MODE` would overcome that. Also, when i create these indexes. Will it screw up any other indexes (like on the ID's for example...)

Comment: There many several factors why in boolean mode not working like mysql version you are having, storage engine etc. However its highly recommended to use fulltext index when you are doing `match .. against`. Now coming to the point will it mess up other index, no it will not your id is primary key and its always index. You can use regular indexes for other columns as well.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Thank you very much. That did the trick. If you could make an answer out of the last comment, I could accept it (or should i remove the question?)

Comment: Ok added as an answer !!

Comment: One more thing -- Don't use '%'; that's for `LIKE`, not `FULLTEXT`.

Comment: @RickJames thank you for the additional information. Will bear that in mind the next time ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many several factors why in `boolean mode` not working

- like mysql version you are having,
- storage engine etc.

However its highly recommended to use fulltext index when you are doing `match .. against` since this is what it is meant for.

Now coming to the point will it mess up other index, no it will not your id is primary key and its always index. You can use regular indexes for other columns as well.